# lambda calculus: predecessor function

Tags: lambda-calculus

Apparently this expression can be used to calculate the predecessor of a given church numeral:

$\renewcommand{\l}{\lambda}$
$\l n.(n\ \l p . (p.2,\ s p.2)\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0})).1$

$<tuple>.n$ being the projection onto the $n$th element.

Now, applying this to some number, let's say $3$ I get:

$\l n.(n\ \l p . (p.2,\ s\ p.2)\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0})).1\ \overline{3}$

$\rightarrow (\overline{3}\ ((\overline{0},\ \overline{0}).2,\ s\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0}).2)).1$

$\rightarrow (\overline{3}\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{1})).1$

I assume I made some mistake here, because this makes no sense, because the expression is not a tuple, so there can be no projection being applied to it. Well, maybe I just need to unfold the expression further...

$\rightarrow ((\l f. \l x. f(f(f\ x)))\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{1})).1$

$\rightarrow ((\l x. (\overline{0},\ \overline{1})((\overline{0},\ \overline{1})((\overline{0},\ \overline{1})\ x)))\ ).1$

No.. this does not look any better... I can't apply $x$ the the right most/ inner most tuple, no any of the tuples to any other tuple... so... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is where you go from

$$
\lambda n.(n\ \lambda p . (p.2,\ s\ p.2)\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0})).1\ \overline{3}
$$

to

$$
(\overline{3}\ ((\overline{0},\ \overline{0}).2,\ s\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0}).2)).1\;.
$$

In lambda calculus, function application is by convention left-associative, so

$$
\lambda n.(n\ \lambda p . (p.2,\ s\ p.2)\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0})).1\ \overline{3}
$$

is

$$
((\overline3\ \lambda p . (p.2,\ s\ p.2))\ (\overline{0},\ \overline{0})).1
$$

Comment: some mathjax errors in your answer.

Comment: @linear_combinatori_probabi: Thanks; someone fixed it now. Interesting; this was caused by [this fix](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130) that restricted the scope of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` to individual posts – I'd reused the command `\l` defined as a shorthand for `\lambda` in the question.